# How to call member functions from their address

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I have a function that resides in a class in an application my objective is to inject a dll into the target proccess and call that member function by its address.
Here is the function:

```
void GameAudio::StopAllSounds(void) // this is at address 0x004A0656
```

I have tried calling it like this

```
typedef void(__stdcall * caller)(void);
caller call = (caller)0x004A0656;
```

I have used everything: `__stdcall` , `__cdecl`, `__thiscall` you name it.

Comment: Are you sure it's always it the same address??

Comment: What happens when you try to call it? Have you tried to step through the call in a debugger? And also remember that all class member functions have an implicit `this` argument.

Comment: when i try call it it just crashes

Comment: @user1205008 - If you use the variety techniques that are available from the C++ language with a good design you do not need to call member functions via an address. Use overriding instead and virtual members.

Comment: You have to know the C++ ABI that is used by the application. Unfortunately this is a very non-portable topic, and it can depend o as much as the compiler *version* that was used. You will have to pass an instance pointer somehow, but the only exact specification for how to do this is the ABI.

Comment: To call an object's method, you need to know the object's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class's non-`static` member function signature is different than the normal function.
For example,

```
class X {
public:
  void foo ();
};
void foo ();
```

In above case `X::foo()` and `::foo()` are different from each other. Remember that, `X::foo()` under the hood is somewaht like:

```
void X::foo (X* const this);
             ^^^^^ implicitly added
```

Thus what you are attempting to do would result in an **undefined behavior**.

If you insists to call the member function using its address, then better to make it a `static` member function.

```
class X {
public:
  static void foo ();
};
void foo ();
```

Signature for `X::foo()` and `::foo()` are same.

**Edit**: From your comment, it seems that you don't have the control over the source code. I would suggest to use the proper calling convention for the function signature instead of hard coded address. Pseudo code

```
typedef void (GameAudio::*caller_type)();
caller_type caller = &GameAudio::StopAllSounds;
GameAudio object;
(object.*caller)();
```

Comment: yes but you must renember that this function is in a application that i do not have the source code to so i cannot change the function to static

Comment: @user1205008, with normal member function --> "you shouldn't" do it. For `static` member function or the function in `namespace` scope, you may do it. But, I still doubt the need to use an address. Why you want to use address ? It will make your code non-portable.

Comment: im only targeting a specific application that i do not have the source to so i would have to use addresses

Comment: @user1205008, Instead of using hard coded address, why can't you assign the function to a proper pointer ? I am editing my answer to address that.

Comment: i would not be able to do that because there would be no way of assigning the right function to a pointer without the address

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax in C++ for what you are doing.
Note that the function could even be virtual, and so you'd be calling the wrong function.

The easiest way is to change it/ into/add a non member function, or a static member function, with an additional `GameAudio*` parameter. That function could be easily be called using a pointer-to function.

If you still want to call the member function directly your best bet is probably to use assembler. The problem then is the portability: your solution will depend on the compiler, SO, architecture and maybe even the ABI version.

Comment: ok i hear you , so bassicaly if i do not have the source to this certain application and to call this function that resides in a class/struct would be impossible? btw i can tell if the function is virtual or not and this specific function is not

Comment: @user1205008 - It is not easy to know if it is virtual. And even if it is, your pointer can be a pointer to the real function or a pointer to the vtable-entry or to a vtable-thunk... That will depend on where you found that number. The best way to know is to disassemble the program and look around that address. And it is certainly not impossible, if you write the call in assembler, as the compiler does it. It is just tricky.